# How to remove an IList<Class> value using dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, ilist

For example I have a class named Temp then I assigned values to it using an `IList<Temp>`.
After populating the `IList<Temp>` I created a dictionary and assign an int key to each object.
My question is that how do I remove from IList and dictionary the temp_value with the name b and a with a key value of "2"?

```
class Temp
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Temp(string n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Temp> temp_value = new List<Temp>();

        temp_value.Add(new Temp("a")
        {
            name = "a",
        });

        temp_value.Add(new Temp("b")
        {
            name = "b",
        });

        temp_value.Add(new Temp("b")
        {
            name = "b",
        });

        Dictionary<int, Temp> dic = new Dictionary<int, Temp>();

        for (int i = 0; i < temp_value.Count; i++)
        {
            dic.Add(i, temp_value[i]);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question more concerning keeping the IList and IDictionary synchronised, or simply removing items from an IDictionary?

Comment: I also want the object with the name value b to be removed when i removed it from dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dict.remove(2)

This is the simplest way

Since you added the items in dictionary at same index as list.

So if you use dict.remove(2)than you can use IList.remove at(2)

Comment: Thanks! Forgot the `RemoveAt()`